# Which actors in the Arrowverse have previously played DC Comics characters?

Tags: arrowverse

Are there actors in the Arrowverse who have previously played DC Comics characters?

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote? I hope it's not because this is a self-answered question, since they are [encouraged on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If it's something else, please let me know so that I can improve the question.

Comment: How can this be _too broad_ @AJ?

Comment: @AJ Not sure how that means there are too many possible answers if one answer contains all the actors.

Comment: @Thunderforge Never mind. BTW +1 for the efforts in answer.

Comment: @Thunderforge - your answer (currently) doesn't contain all the actors, e.g. __Victor Garber__ voiced _Sinestro_ in __[Green Lantern: First Flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern:_First_Flight)__ and __Summer Glau__ voiced _Supergirl_ in __[Superman/Batman: Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman:_Apocalypse)__ - But instead of "too broad" I'd rather categorize this question as a "list question" and/or "Trivia".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, there's lots!

#### [Amanda Pays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanda_Pays)

Dr. Christina "Tina" McGee in both the [the 1990 version of *The Flash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanda_Pays)

[image: Dr. Tina McGee, The Flash 1990]

…and the 2014 *The Flash* series

[image: Dr. Tina McGee, The Flash 2014]

It's fun seeing her interested in Henry Allen, since her character and John Wesley Shipp's character had romantic feelings in the 1990s show.

#### [Alex Désert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_D%C3%A9sert)

Julio Mendez, Barry Allen's coworker and close friend, in the 1990 *The Flash* TV series.

[image: Julio Mendez, The Flash 1990]

And **Captain** Julio Mendez in the "Flashpoint" timeline of the 2014 *The Flash*:

[image: Captain Julio Mendez, The Flash 2014]

#### [Brandon Routh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Routh)

Superman in *Superman Returns*

[image: Superman in Superman Returns]

And Ray Palmer (The Atom) in *Arrow* and *Legends of Tomorrow*

[image: Ray Palmer, Arrow and Legends of Tomorrow][image: The Atom, Arrow and Legends of Tomorrow]

#### [Clancy Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clancy_Brown)

The voice of Lex Luthor in *Superman: The Animated Series* and the rest of the DC animated universe (as well as [other voice roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clancy_Brown#DC_Universe_roles))

[image: Clancy Brown voicing Lex Luthor]

And General Wade Eiling in the 2014 *The Flash*

[image: General Wade Eiling, The Flash]

#### John Wesley Shipp

The Flash himself in the 1990 *The Flash* series.

[image: The Flash 1990]

And Barry Allen's father, Henry Allen, in the 2014 *The Flash*, as well as Earth-3 Jay Garrick

[image: Henry Allen, The Flash 2014] [image: Earth 3 Jay Garrick, The Flash 2014]

#### [Mark Hamill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill)

As the voice of The Joker in Batman: The Animated Series

[image: Mark Hamill as the Joker, Batman the Animated Series]

And as the Trickster in the 2014 *The Flash*

[image: The Trickster, The Flash 2014]

<sub>In his first episode, he also dramatically tells another guest character "I am your father!"</sub>

#### [Neal McDonough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neal_McDonough)

Voiced Oliver Queen in *DC Showcase: Green Arrow*, then fought against him as Damien Dahrk in *Arrow*

[image: Damien Dahrk, Arrow]

He has also done video game voice work as Barry Allen/The Flash in *Injustice: Gods Among Us* and Floyd Lawton/Deadshot in *Batman: Assault on Arkham*.

#### [Tara Strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_Strong)

As the voice of Harley Quinn in many Batman-related media:

[image: Tara Strong voicing Harley Quinn]

She has a one-line voiceover role as Harley Quinn in *Arrow*

[image: Harley Quinn, Arrow]

*"Do you cuties need some counseling? I'm a trained therapist."*

Comment: Don't know about the question; but I liked the answer. +1.

Comment: Great answer, Mark Hamel was also the Trickster in the 90's Flash. Then there is Laura Vandermoot (?) who was Supergirl on Smallville and a Brainiac type villain on Supergirl. Plus Dean Caine and Helen Slater who played Superman and Supergirl in previous roles and are now Supergirls adoptive parents.

Comment: @JasonK I'll see about adding Mark Hamill in the 90s Flash. As for the others, *Supergirl* [isn't officially part of the Arrowverse](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61915/12783) although there are plenty of fans that do consider it to be. Perhaps I'll add it as an addendum.

Comment: @Thunderforge Well, Flash does cross over to her world in Supergirl season 1 and I hear there will be a Flash/Arrow/Legends/Supergirl 4 way crossover this year but yeah, it is the most loosely connected one for sure.