# Do the showrunners consider Supergirl and Constantine to be part of the Arrowverse?

Tags: arrowverse, supergirl, constantine-tv

According to Wikipedia's [article on the Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse), the Arrowverse consists of four shows: *Arrow*, *The Flash*, *Legends of Tomorrow*, and the animated series *Vixen*. It lists *Supergirl* as a crossover, but not part of the universe itself.

However, some fans count Supergirl as part of the Arrowverse, since there was the *Supergirl* crossover "Worlds Finest" where Flash traveled to her alternate earth.

Do the showrunners consider Constantine and Supergirl to be part of the Arrowverse?

Comment: Check the article [phantom42](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1046/phantom42) linked in this [message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32801616#32801616) in [Agents of Nothing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19346/agents-of-nothing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way *they* define the term, no; the way *fans* define the term, yes.

There have been several cases where they producers have used the term "Arrowverse", or have otherwise described the "world" where *Flash* and *Arrow* exist. In those cases, they have always kept *Supergirl* separate.

Early on, in one of the [first interviews](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/supergirl-flash-ep-shoots-down-845560) about *Supergirl*, Andrew Kriesberg said:

> And quite frankly, just making the Arrow-verse, which is what we call Legends, Flash and Arrow work and then making Supergirl work, it's enough of a challenge without having to add a fourth player."

Of course, this was before there were even plans for a crossover. Obviously, those plans changed: the shows crossed over, and they will again. However, the producers still consider them to exist in two separate universes, as in this [most recent](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/10/07/supergirl-season-2-cw-spoilers) interview with Kriesberg:

> Not for her entire world, but Kara will be traveling from her dimension to our dimension, “our” being the world that The Flash, Arrow, and Legends lives in.

---

However, it's clear that the producers consider the four shows to be *strongly connected* in the sense that characters can travel freely between the *Arrow*/*Flash* universe and the *Supergirl* universe. There will be an episode of *Supergirl* that occurs as part of the Arrowverse crossover event (meaning the same continuous story will take place on all four shows).

Also, we already know that the Arrowverse is a multiverse, and from the perspective of *Flash*,  *Supergirl* just exists in one of those other parallel Earths (no number, though).

So, for all meaningful purposes, *Supergirl* is part of the Arrowverse in the sense that you mean the set of shows with shared characters and interactions. It's at least as strongly connected to the Arrowverse as *Constantine*, for example.

But it is *not* part of the "world" of *Flash* or *Arrow* and there are no plans to merge those two universes together.

Answer (score 4):

According to this quote from [Andrew Kreisberg](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/10/07/supergirl-season-2-cw-spoilers) the creator of the 4 shows

> **As revealed during The Flash-Supergirl crossover last year, Supergirl**
>   **hails from a different universe.** **Are you planning on bringing**
>   **Supergirl into our universe?** Not for her entire world, but Kara will
>   be traveling from her dimension to our dimension, “our” being the
>   world that The Flash, Arrow, and Legends lives in.

The SuperGirl's world will remain outside of the arrowverse world.

Comment: I don't think Kara staying in her own world is definitive proof that she's not part of the Arrowverse. After all, Earth-2 is part of the Arrowverse (because it's part of *The Flash*), even though it's not the world that the shows are primarily set in.

Comment: @Thunderforge updated the quote and link to the actual interview

Comment: what about Constantine